# How I can stop editing select box in inspector code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is my select tag:

```
<select disabled name="orgn">
  <option>Something</option>
</select>
```

Here when I inspect code it allow to change means if I remove the disabled it will enable the select box.

Is their is any way to stop editing in select box when inspect ?

Comment: No, there isn't any.

Comment: None at all. This is why user input validation on the server side is absolutely critical.

Comment: It's simple, You can't

Comment: No this is not possible but you can find out javascript/jquery by which user can not inspect on page.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that, that's why you never leave the validation only on the frontend part, you must always keep in mind to do proper validation on the backend side as well.

That being said there are some techniques that some developers use to block the keys that open (f12) the inspect element or they block the right-click but you can't completely block the user from using the tools to edit your html, so best way to make sure that the data the user is typing are safe, you must do a backend validation.